# Bugzilla error after installation: "TEST-FAILED Web Server is not executing CGI files"

Tags: linux, apache, bugzilla

I want to install Bugzilla on my linux server. The installation was successful, but it gives this error:

```
TEST-FAILED Web Server is not executing CGI files
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Bugzilla configuration guide](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/2.18/html/configuration.html):

**2.2.4.1. Apache httpd**

To configure your Apache web server to work with Bugzilla, do the following:

1. Load httpd.conf in your editor. In Fedora and Red Hat Linux, this file is found in /etc/httpd/conf.
2. Apache uses  directives to permit fine-grained permission setting. Add the following lines to a directive that applies to the location of your Bugzilla installation. (If such a section does not exist, you'll want to add one.) In this example, Bugzilla has been installed at /var/www/html/bugzilla.

Check this:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/bugzilla>
   AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
   Options +Indexes +ExecCGI
   DirectoryIndex index.cgi
   AllowOverride Limit
</Directory>
```

These instructions allow Apache to run .cgi files found within the bugzilla directory; instructs the server to look for a file called index.cgi if someone only types the directory name into the browser; and allows Bugzilla's .htaccess files to override global permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Changing SELinux settings to permissive worked for me.

In Fedora Core and RedHat Enterprise, edit /etc/selinux/config and you will see some lines like this:

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
# enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
# permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
# disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=enforcing
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of these two values:
# targeted - Only targeted network daemons are protected.
# strict - Full SELinux protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

... just change `SELINUX=enforcing` to `SELINUX=permissive` and you're done.

Answer (score -2):

You might try to read the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/), it should contain everything you need.